# Weird layout appear with google recaptcha in IE Browser

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, recaptcha

Im using google recaptcha, as shown in the image below, when I click the captcha check box, a weird line shows up in my page. Even I set height for the div or remove css related code. The line still shows up eventually. It only appear in IE browser and works fine in other browser, is it a bug between google recaptcha and IE browser?

[image]

**Here is the code**

```
                        <div class="row" >
                            <div  align="center">
                                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="somedatasitekeyhere"
                                     data-theme="light" data-size="normal">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: can you host the whole code for preview ? At high level like some other css is impacting the layout.

Comment: do u mean the whole code of this page? its weird, even console in inspect element also does not show any error

Comment: Yes, can you host the source code along with linked css file here or in JSFiddle/CodePen ? That would help to analyse the code.